# setOnUtteranceProgressListener() not always working

Tags: android

While working on a TextToSpeech project I have experienced the following:

1. If I use `speak(CharSequence text, int queueMode, Bundle params, String utteranceId)` to speak text, utterance listener works as expected.
2. If I added a mapping using `addSpeech(String text, String packagename, int resourceId)`  and then use `speak(CharSequence text, int queueMode, Bundle params, String utteranceId)`, mapping works (sound played), but the utterance listener methods are not getting called.
3. If I use `addEarcon(String earcon, String packagename, int resourceId)` and then use `playEarcon(String earcon, int queueMode, Bundle params, String utteranceId)`, mapping works (sound played), but the utterance listener methods are not getting called.
4. If I use `playSilentUtterance(long durationInMs, int queueMode, String utteranceId)`, utterance listener works as expected.
5. The problems in 2 and 3 are solved by using the methods that were deprecated in API level 21, for example using:

   HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
   params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, String key);  (deprecated)

In case of number 2:

```
addSpeech(String text, String packagename, int resourceId);
```

and then

```
speak(String text, int queueMode, HashMap<String, String> params);  (deprecated method)
```

and in case of number 3:

```
addEarcon(String earcon, String packagename, int resourceId)
```

and then

```
playEarcon(String earcon, int queueMode, HashMap<String, String> params);  (deprecated method)
```

Has anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the condition for the different cases of speaking which may confuse other users who are suggested to adjust initializing order.

User have to create parameter for UtteranceProgressListener to track.